# Responsive email - Gmail for iOS breaks nested tables

Tags: gmail, html-email

My responsive email template is showing a distinct problem when it comes to testing for Gmail viewed on iOS. Where the two parts are meant to stack are in fact two tables nested inside another one. When I view the code in my email (on desktop with narrowed browser window), after sending the test, I see that gmail has un-nested these tables. The result on the appearance is not what i am looking for. In the screenshot the highlighted table is supposed to be inside the table above with the 100% width.

I have been using this template for the past few months and it was never doing this, have there been developments with gmail?
[image: code from inspector]

Comment: Each of those tables are children of different DIV tags and are not nested within each other.  The 100% table ends before the 200px table begins.

Comment: There are not supposed to be any div tags anywhere, those are created by gmail. I will post a fiddle soon that shows what my code looks like.

Comment: that will definitely help figure it out. As far as I am aware, GMail did not change anything with their processors that would affect nested tables...

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/roob/sdhua14d/   I only included the troublesome part, the rest of the email is showing ok. The template I am using is based on a hybrid approach. The comented conditional statements are for Outlook

Comment: going off just the html in the fiddle, this works perfectly in all iOS and even on the Gmail iOS app. I did an acid test through Email on Acid and a live test and had no issue.  It could potentially be a validation issue that is corrected or overlooked in all the other pre-processors.

Comment: Not sure how it is looking fine on your end, the code is clearly changed as I explained, please look at the screenshot: http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee455/roobp57/Random%20Stuff/Screen%20Shot%202015-07-29%20at%2012.08.49%20PM.png. Also look at the other scrnshots for my results which are based on a test email sent to myself using Cheetah (live test). It does come out looking right on every other client. http://i1228.photobucket.com/albums/ee455/roobp57/Random%20Stuff/IMG_1708.png

Comment: i should add, in previous email tests components that are supposed to stack would not do so in gmail-iOS, whereas they do so in every other client. At least the structure was intact. Now, however, due to the nested table being undone, stacking components are in fact stacked but shifted to the left. Can not align-center as that would mess up the desktop version.

Comment: I am not sure what to tell you, Sending it from my Exact Target account and through a commercial SMTP, sending via Thunderbird and running through Email on Acid all show it with still nested and stacked in Gmail on all browsers, in iOS mail, in Android mail and on the GMail app in iOS and Android (although Android app is a little off since it is a wider screen). Perhaps the ESP or client you are using manipulates code prior to sending it?

Comment: It should not stack in Gmail-iOS, I know it is supposed to stack everywhere but from experience with this template gmail-iOS holds it all together the same way as it would appear on desktop. Thats only until now with this case. As you may have noticed in your tests the social media blocks are not centered. If they stacked properly they would be.

Comment: I might give in to the fact that responsive components are now stacking in gmail-iOS when they would not do so previously. Just have to figure a way of having them come out centered. Thank you for your time.

Comment: revisiting this: I figured what was going on but not gonna go into it (not important). Can I ask Gortonington in your tests on the Gmail for iOS was the stacked content centered? On my end if it is stacked/centered on mobile then it comes out the same on desktop version of Gmail where it should be on one row. I'm having trouble figuring how to have both: one row in Gmail-desktop and stacked/centered on Gmail-iOS.

Comment: I think that gmail on ios breaks nested tables from some degree. I'm experiencing the following: the same email, when the first on an email thread (conversation), or not in a thread at all, is looking fine. But when somewhere down the thread it's broken.

Comment: I finally figured my problem from above, only posting here since it seems people are looking at this thread. I realized I need to have one image, or element, spanning the entire width of the email with an undeclared width. Doing this will keep the layout intact and will shrink the email in proportion. If however I put width=100%, which makes sense for fluid width, then Gmail will un-nest tables and create the havoc that made me post here. Even more bizarre is Gmail for Android: have not figured how to have block come out centered in that.